# Where is DXA ViewBag RegionName set?

Tags: dxa

In the DXA Example Site a `RegionName` is set in the `ViewBag`.  Where is this  defined?

> \Site\Areas\Core\Views\Entity\Partials\Teaser-ImageOverlay.cshtml

```
if (ViewBag.RegionName == "Hero")
```

Comment: Do you mean when the `RegionName` is added to the `ViewBag`, why is that important exactly?

Comment: How is it added and from where?  Would like to understand how it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewBag.RegionName` contains a bit of context information for the view. It is populated by the DXA controllers, (see [Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.SetupViewData](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/2bd467e01e79850e6e9e937ac41a666080b767a6/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Controllers/BaseController.cs)). It does not apply to page views and region views.

Which `RegionName` is used is configured in the CT (component template) in the CMS, in the template metadata field `Region Name`. If the `Region Name` field is empty the default is the region view name (excluding module name) from the `Region View Name` field.

The Core module uses the `Viewbag.RegionName` in the partial view `Teaser-ImageOverlay` ([see source](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-net/Core/Areas/Core/Views/Entity/Partials/Teaser-ImageOverlay.cshtml)).

```
 if (ViewBag.RegionName == "Hero")
```

Answer (score 5):

`RegionName` is set in the corresponding ComponentTemplate's `RegionView` Field

Comment: Actually the `RegionName` comes from the `Region Name` field. Only when that is empty the `Region View Name` is used.